# Collect Redoc FastAPI from some instances on an one page

Tags: fastapi, redoc

Is there any convenient way to put Redoc together from some insurances running on several ports, for instance:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/redoc
- http://127.0.0.1:8001/redoc
- http://127.0.0.1:8002/redoc
- http://127.0.0.1:8003/redoc

Each instance presents itself Fast API with certain endpoints.

I'd want to have the starting page where the all endpoints would be presented, let's say http://127.0.0.1:8004/redoc

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in your build pipeline, using the `redocly join` command (docs: https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/join/ and disclaimer: I work for Redocly). Grab each of the OpenAPI specifications, and put them into one combined file, would that do what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks relevant. Is it possible on free plan to collect 4 APIs on one page?

Comment: Yes, the CLI tool is open source and free to use. Collect as many APIs as you like! The free plan would let you publish the docs to the Redocly platform if you wanted to.